# Gitlab Runner cache in a PVC

Tags: kubernetes, caching, gitlab-ci-runner, k3s

I'm using a private kubernetes cluster at home and want to deploy Gitlab CI/CD.
I've installed it using Helm.

My Gitlab Runner seems ok but I want it to mount a PVC as cache directory.

My helm values look like this :

```yaml
runners:
  privileged: true
  # runner configuration, where the multi line strings is evaluated as
  # template so you can specify helm values inside of it.
  #
  # tpl: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function
  # runner configuration: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      cache_dir = "/cache"
      [runners.cache]
        type = "file"
        [runners.cache.file]
          path = "/cache"
      [runners.kubernetes]
        disable_cache = false
        helper_image = "gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:alpine3.13-arm64-bleeding"
        image = "arm64v8/ubuntu:22.04"
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        privileged = true
        pull_policy = ["always"]
        [runners.kubernetes.cache]
          [runners.kubernetes.cache.file]
            type = "file"
            path = "/cache"
        [runners.kubernetes.volumes.pvc]
          name = gitlab-pvc
          mount_path = /cache
## Additional volumeMounts to add to the runner container
##
volumeMounts:
  - name: gitlab-pvc
    mountPath: /cache

## Additional volumes to add to the runner deployment
##
volumes: 
  - name: gitlab-pvc
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: gitlab-pvc
```

PVC `gitlab-pvc`is correctly mounted on the original Gitlab Runner but not on the job pods it creates.

I also have the following error :
`ERROR: Could not create cache adapter error=cache factory not found: factory for cache adapter "" was not registered`

I don't really understand how config.toml works for runners

Comment: Most probably because your PVC is RWO (read write once) which cannot be mounted by multiple pods. You have better luck using NFS volume if you want multiple job pods to share the same volume.